# List C++ Не выводит список

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы, std-list

Вот,учу списки, и не понимаю почему не выводит отсортированный список.

Выводит только если ввести так:

> copy(myList.begin(), myList.end(), ostream_iterator(cout," "));

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>     
#include <iterator> 
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int> myList; 
   srand(time(NULL));

   for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
       myList.push_back(rand()%20); 
   }
   list<int>::iterator v = myList.begin();
   list<int>::iterator v1 =myList.end();
   cout << "Список: ";
   for( v ; v!=v1;v++)
   {
     cout<<*v<<" ";
   }

   myList.sort();
   cout << "\nОтсортированный список: ";

   for( v ; v!=v1;v++)
   {
     cout<<*v<<" ";
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не выводит потому что во втором цикле `v==v1` и он просто не выполняетcя. 
Нужно так:

```
for ( list<int>::const_iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++)
{
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно было просто перед вторым циклом (или внутри него) установить итератора на начало     `v = myList.begin();`